# Open overlay (modal dialog) jquery tools on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, overlay, jquery-tools

I was trying to open jquery tools overlay on page load. The default method for this "load()" not work and there is no error message inside the console. If I use .click() javascript method it work ok but .click() doesn't works on all browsers. Here is the code:

```
$(function() {
 //getoverlay = $("#atoaaa[rel]").overlay({mask: '#000'}); 
 //getoverlay.click();
     $("#content_598").overlay({mask: '#000', closeOnClick: false, load: false}).load();
});
```

This is the code of overlay module - https://gist.github.com/joshcartme/9063054

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is parameter data('overlay') load after method overlay()

```
 $("#content_598").overlay({mask: '#000', closeOnClick: false, load: false});
 $('#content_598').data('overlay').load();
```